# Explanation for line in set_query()

Tags: php

I need help to understand the following code.
What I want to know is the code line in the set_query($data,$limit_enable).
If any help regarding the matter would be highly appreciated.

```
function get_data($data){

    $out = array();
    $this->set_query($data,$limt_enabled);
    //some code
}

function set_query($data,$limit_enable){

    $data['selection'] =  isset($data['selection'])? $data['selection']: 'task_master.staff_id,staff.full_name,creator_staff.full_name AS creator' ;
    //some code
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `$this->set_query($data,$limt_enabled);` is calling the `set_query()` method of this same class and `set_query()` has one ternary expression which is

```
$data['selection'] =  isset($data['selection'])? $data['selection']: 'task_master.staff_id,staff.full_name,creator_staff.full_name AS creator' ;
```

It means

```
if( isset($data['selection']) )
{
    $data['selection'] = $data['selection'];
}
else
{
    $data['selection'] = 'task_master.staff_id,staff.full_name,creator_staff.full_name AS creator'
}
```

I'm not sure from which `framework` you have got it but it looks like that, if already `$data['selection']` is not set for selection from table then set the selection criterion something like

```
select task_master.staff_id, staff.full_name, creator_staff.full_name
```

Which is actually going to be used for selecting some table fields and these are

```
 staff_id field from table `task_master
 full_name field from table `staff
 full_name field from table `creator_staff
```

Also it's setting an alias for this selection AS `creator`.